# Displaying data from mysql database in webpage using session

Tags: php, mysql, session

I simply need to display data from a mysql database. All the data is already stored in the database when the user submits the form. So in the landing page after the user is logged in, I need to display the users full name as well as a few other columns from the database table. In essence, I want the page to say Welcome *fullname*, then display some other colums from the database in a table. How should I code this using session?
NOTE: I have tried to use sessions to display the user's full name and current balance after logging in.
My code below:

```
<?php
    // Connect to database display welcome Full name, then date, name, credit, debit, balance
    session_start();
    $fullname="";

    $currentbalance="";
    if (!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
    }
    echo $_SESSION['fullname'];


    ?>
    Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['fullname']; ?>.
    <table border ="1">
    <th>DATE </th>
    <th>'.$fullname.' </th>
    <th>CREDIT </th>
    <th>DEBIT</th>
    <th><?php echo $_SESSION['currentbalance']; ?</th>
    </table>
```

Comment: you  need to assigned value to variable `$_SESSION['fullname'] = $fullname` and before using it you need to start the session

Comment: ok i will try that now. Is that all I didn't do though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    // Connect to database display welcome Full name, then date, name, credit, debit, balance
    if (!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
    }
    $fullname="";
    $currentbalance="";

    $_SESSION['fullname']=$fullname;
$_SESSION['currentbalance ']=$currentbalance ; // Where $fullname and $currentbalance must be already defined by the query


    ?>
    Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['fullname']; ?>.
    <table border ="1">
    <th>DATE </th>
    <th>'.$fullname.' </th>
    <th>CREDIT </th>
    <th>DEBIT</th>
    <th><?php echo $_SESSION['currentbalance']; ?</th>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you logged in you need to store `fullname` in `session` like

```
$_SESSION['fullname'] = $_REQUEST['fullname'];
```

After `login` , you can get this `fullname` on homepage.

```
$session_name = $_SESSION['fullname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

During login just store the user id into session, so you could easily got all the information from database by this user id.

```
"select * from `users` where id='".$_SESSION['userid']."'"
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I store the user id into session?Because the user's full name is only supposed to be displayed after log in

Comment: If you'r about show the full name only then store the full name in session.

Answer (score 0):

use this code, you put the session in curly braces.

```
"select * from `users` where id={$_SESSION['userid']}"
```

Comment: Please use prepared statements rather than putting values directly into query.